# Healpy and Canopy

Tags: healpy, canopy

Canopy Currently Does not have Healpy as an available package. I have tried to install Healpy by hand using the following commands:

Download healpy.1.6.2.tar.gz and unzip to /home/user/healpy.1.6.2/

Check that canopy python is default Python... which python returns /home/user/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python

in command prompt in healpy.1.6.2 folder run: python setup.py build,

in same folder run: sudo python setup.py install

both return successfully

run python in command prompt:

python

> > import numpy
> >
> > import healpy
> >
> > Traceback (most recent call last):
> >
> > File "", line 1, in
> >
> > File "healpy/**init**.py", line 34, in
> >
> > from pixelfunc import (ma, mask_good, mask_bad,
> >
> > File "healpy/pixelfunc.py", line 87, in
> >
> > import _healpy_pixel_lib as pixlib

Running Ubuntu 11.10, there are previous versions of EPD and python installed which might mess things up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you downloaded  healpy from pypi?

Comment: Yup, that's where I downloaded it from.

Comment: Can you paste your build output somewhere?

Comment: Easy instructions for installing Healpy in Ubuntu 14.04: [Installation problems with Healpy python-3..4 on ubuntu-14.04](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256019/installation-problems-with-healpy-python-3-4-on-ubuntu-14-04) using the python-healpy package from Ubuntu 14.10 universe repository.